# Математическая прогрессия неправильно увеличивается

Tags: visual-studio, математика

Метод некорректно выдает значения, точнее прогрессия неправильно увеличивается.

**Пояснение** : Существует три входных параметра : number - первое неизменяемое число в последовательности, addition - число, которое каждый раз увеличивается на саму себя, count - количество прохождений цикла. Приведу как пример :
Входные параметры (2, 3, 5), ожидаемое 40, т.к. 2 + (2+3) + (2+3+3) + (2+3+3+3) + (2+3+3+3+3) равняется 40. Но в моем случае выходит 203, сама строчка каждого прохода выглядит так : 7
15
29
55
105
203.

```
 public static int Calculate(int number, int addition, int count)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            sum = 2;
            sum = sum + (number + addition);
            addition+= addition;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Хотелось бы понять - как правильно реализовывать такого рода прогрессии. За любую помощь - спасибо !

Comment: `//sum = 2;` *(нужно ещё 3 символа...)*

Comment: А как вы это проверяете? Покажите код.

Comment: @AK То есть, Вы предлагаете эту строчку оставить?

Comment: @aepot, Добрый День - я решаю вручную на бумаге, а потом сверяю с результатом программы.

Comment: @AK , а если поточнее, а то я дуб дубнем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не прибавляете первоначальное значение `addition` к текущему на каждой итерации, а увеличиваете текущее значение этой пременной в два раза.

```js
function sumN(number, delta, count) {
  let sum = 0;
  let dN = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sum = sum + (number + dN);
    dN += delta;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumN(2, 3, 5));
```

Comment: За что минусуете? Человек помог, подобрал результат.

Comment: Спасибо огромное ! И всем остальным тоже ) Хорошего вам дня .

Comment: @Surrender Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Comment: Чет я не вижу, где в вопросе тег `javascript`...

Comment: @aepot Меня это никогда не останавливало.

Comment: Ваше право, я не против, просто удивило.

Comment: Если у вас нет шарповой IDE под рукой, вы же можете такие простые штуки на https://sharplab.io или https://dotnetfiddle.net писать.

Comment: @aepot Я считаю, что конкретный язык не имеет к этому вопросу никакого отношения.

Comment: Тогда стоило бы из него убрать языковой тег, если по логике рассуждать. И добавить тег "алгоритм", тогда хоть псевдокод будет смотреться уместно. Я мог ответ и на Erlang или F# написать (если был бы язык не важен), там бы решение выглядело локаничнее, но все же предпочел язык, ожидаемый автором. UPD: убрал.

Answer (score 2):

А можно вообще без цикла, если вспомнить форму сложения арифметической прогрессии:

```js
number * count + addition * count * (count - 1) / 2
```